# Obtaining range of values in zones created using Slice tool

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis-10.4, reclassify

I have to reclassify rasters in my workflow into two zones using natural jenks. The [Slice](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/slice.htm) tool does the job perfectly, but I would like to print the range of values out in my script to be used as variables and written in csvs. Is there some sort of command I can use that will print out the threshold value? I should mention that the input raster is a 32bit float which complicates things a little. My alternative is to use Zonal Statistics and derive min and max for these ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using Zonal Statistics as Table Tool and using the Max or Min value of the two zones.